# Force keep focus on anchor when click

Tags: javascript, focus

I am using modal-popup.js, and when this anchor is clicked, the modal pop-up is displayed; however this removes focus from the anchor.

Is there any way to force the browser to keep focus on anchor?

```
<a href="#">anchor</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="#" id="link">test</a>
```

$("#link").focus();

This will work.

Answer (score 1):

If you give your anchor tag an id or a class, you can use the DOM Element `focus()` method.

In the modal's click handler method, select the anchor tag that you wish to remain focused, and call the `focus()` method, like so:

```
document.querySelector("#anchor_id").focus();
```